# Java Architecture - Self managed classes vs Manager classes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, structure

I am using Spring with Hibernate.

My hibernate model I am using is 'NodeInstanceLog' which is the object that is retrieved from the database.

My current structure:

[image: current structure]

At the moment, NodeInstanceLogDAO is handling the retrieving of the data from the database.

The other option would be to change my structure to make it so NodeInstanceLog is fetchable and make it manage itself. Ie being able to retrieve its data from the database.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of separation of concern.  A model represents a part of your problem domain, while the DAO is concerned with getting data in and out of a datastore.  Two completely different problems, requiring dedicated classes.

In general, the more you split up responsibilities, the more modular your code base is with many advantages: 
* our brains tend to be good in focussing on one small thing at a time, so reading (=maintaining) your code will be easier, as it's more structured.
* testing is easier when different responsibilities are separated in small classes: a test can manipulate one simple focussed class at a time
* reuse is more likely: if you want to do something else with a model instance that has nothing to do with DAO, that DAO code in there would be dragged into the other thing you wanna do for nothing

Anyway, there is probably a lot more to say.  Try googling "separation of concern", "loose coupling", ...  But take it from me: splitting responsibilities is the way to go :)

Comment: So you are saying that, split the responsibilities such that NodeInstanceLog will only hold its data, not fetch itself is the way you would go?

Answer (score 2):

In plain java, using DAOs / Repositories is usually better as otherwise your objects will need to have quite a lot of database logic. Database logic is NOT business logice, and your model should only represent the business model.

Play is a framework that can weave a lot of the persistence logic automagically into your classes (using aspects), in this way your model class has methods to query the DB, but it doesn't have the logic.

If you're learning this stuff, I would suggest you to implement both and experience what pains each solution creates (e.g. how do you deal with transactions? from where do you take a DB Connection?)

I also suggest you to read the book [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/), in particular Active Record (having the logic weaved into your class) and Unit of Work (Hibernate)